# extract specific fields from a file using a character delimiter

Tags: text-processing, awk, gawk, mawk

I have a 1gb file and would like to get the third and fifth fields.

The file is delimited by (,):

**input file:**

```
luis, jose, jesus atoche, mark, john
1,2,3,4,5
aa 1, bb 2, cc3, dd 4, ee5
```

**output file:**

```
jesus atoche, john
3.5
  cc3, ee5
```

I understand that it can be done with the awk commands.

THANKS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something in the lines of

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=","; OFS=","} {print $3, $5}' input_file.csv > output_file.csv
```

Should work

Answer (score 0):

Try     `awk -F"," '{print $3","$5}' <input file name>`